# Whitespace restriction in Id

Tags: xsd

I don't want any whitespaces in my ids. So I made a pattern which forbids it. 
By default Xml parsers trim the attributes' values. I used `<xs:whiteSpace value="preserve"/>` to keep them. 
But my Xml-Schema validator prints this warning:

```
It is an error if 'whiteSpace' is among the members of {facets} of 
{base type definition}, {value} is 'replace' or 'preserve', 
and the {value} of the parent 'whiteSpace' is 'collapse'.
```

This is my whole type:

```
<xs:simpleType name="Id">       
    <xs:restriction base="xs:ID">
        <xs:whiteSpace value="preserve"/>
        <xs:pattern value="[^\s].*[^\s]"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: It means spaces are collapsed in the base type, so you can't restrict whitespaces to preserve as the have already been removed. Is similar as if you try to set a restriction maxInclusive=1000 if the base is xs:byte (max 255), it won't be valid.

Comment: So I have to use key/keyref, where I can set the whitespace property?

Comment: Usually is not really neccesary to disallow whitespaces as in `<id>   myId </id>` the id is `myId` (whitout the spaces even if they appear).